# How long can you keep polyjuice potion before it is no longer usable?

Tags: harry-potter

Harry, Hermione and Ron possess a reserve of polyjuice potion when they go in search of Horcruxes.

It takes months and they use it three times:

- to go to the Ministry of Magic,
- to go to Godric's Hollow,
- to go to Gringotts.

Would this mean the potion always keeps its properties/potential  as long as you haven't added the hair of the person you're turning into.

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Apothecarium_of_Horace_E._F._Slughorn

Comment: I know this wiki but don't find my answer. Is there an expiration date for the potion? before you have added the last ingredient (the hair).

Answer (score 0):

I believe how long a potion lasts depends on the potion itself, but as it's not particularly volatile (without the hair the potion is very thick) it must be storable. A good example would be (the fake) Mad-Eye Moody, who used it for a full year, and although he had the chance to keep making it, and did (Harry was suspected of stealing Snape's stocks), as seen at the end of the film he has many vials to stock up on it, so it must last quite a long time.

Comment: As far as we know, Polyjuice Potion has to be taken every single hour, so the fact that he has many vials isn't necessarily indicative that it keeps for a very long time - he might get through those vials pretty sharpish.